# Theoretical inquiry about overloading and type promotion in java

Tags: java, overloading, type-promotion

If there are two methods like `add(int,long)` and `add(long,int)`, such call `add(10,10)` would be considered as ambiguity.

But what if we have such example, why is it still considered as ambiguity??

```
static void add(short num1, short num2) {
    System.out.println("add(short, short)");
}

static void add(byte num1, long num2) {
    System.out.println("add(byte, long)");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    byte num1 = 10;
    byte num2 = 10;

    add(num1, num2);
}
```

I want to know how the compiler decided that it is ambiguity? while (in my mind) it shouldn't because `add(short, short)` needs two steps of type promotion, and `add(byte, long)` needs three steps of type promotion .. or do I have a misconception??

Comment: Why do you think it's *not* ambiguous?

Comment: I'm asking why is it ambiguous?? can you demonstrate that?

Comment: Which one should it call? Why?

Comment: `bytes` can be `shorts`

Comment: you see, java has type coercion therefore those signatures are ambiguous since the compiler gets troubles on figuring which method you are trying to call.

Comment: @shmosel actually that's my question

Comment: So you don't know which one it should call, but you expect the compiler to know?

Comment: @shmosel please re-read the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [8.4.9. Overloading -
from the Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.9) and the ["overloading resolution procedure"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12) - and, specifically **15.12.2.5. Choosing the Most Specific Method**.

> If more than one member method is both accessible and applicable to a method invocation, it is necessary to choose one to provide the descriptor for the run-time method dispatch. The Java programming language uses the rule that the *most specific* method is chosen.
>
> ..
>
> One applicable method m1 is *more specific* than another applicable method m2, for an invocation with argument expressions e1, ..., ek, *if* any of the following are true:
>
> - [..]
> - m2 is not generic, and m1 and m2 are applicable by strict or loose invocation, and where m1 has formal parameter types S1, ..., Sn and m2 has formal parameter types T1, ..., Tn, *the type Si is more specific than Ti for argument ei for all i (1 ≤ i ≤ n, n = k)*.
> - [..]
>
> ..
>
> *It is possible that no method is the most specific*, because there are two or more methods that are maximally specific .. [there are more rules wrt concrete/abstract..]
>
> **Otherwise, the method invocation is ambiguous, and a compile-time error occurs.**

*The Java compiler just follows these rules*; a different language will follow different rules, and a human might invent their own non-Java rules when deciding which overload to pick..

---

For a method to be selected as *more specific*, it must be *more specific* for all parameters. Thus the example case results in a *ambiguous invocation* when invoked as `add(byte,byte)` because:

- `add(short num1 /* less specific */, short num2 /* MORE specific */)`
- `add(byte num1  /* MORE specific */, long num2  /* less specific */)`.

However, if `add(byte num1, long num2)` was changed to `add(byte num1, short num2)` it would compile because:

- `add(short num1 /* less specific */, short num2 /* as specific */)`
- `add(byte num1  /* MORE specific */, short num2 /* as specific */)`.

The relationship between primitives is in [4.10.1. Subtyping among Primitive Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10): long > int > short > byte:

Comment: Geeze, that set of rules is soo complex so I punted with "..  lots of rules in here .." which doesn't satisfactorily show the exact process taken by the Java compiler..

Comment: Whelp, there is my shot at distilling the relevant rules and selection process. YMMV and tldr; this is Just How Java Is Defined To Work.

Comment: You nailed it bro :)

Answer (score 1):

Matching the actual argument types to the method parameter lists requires type coercion in both cases, so neither is a "perfect" match and therefore ambiguous.  If you add

```
static void add(byte num1, byte num2) {
    System.out.println("add(byte, byte)");
}
```

it's a perfect match and there is no ambiguity.

Comment: I don't think it's because that the both parameters need type promotion, because if we had those methods instead of the mentioned above, `add(int,int)` and `add(long,long)` there would be no ambiguity